# How to call MainPage function from runtime component in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP solution, which contains an UWP project (main file MainPage, index.html, this is upper level) and a Window Runtime Component (main file Bridge.cs, this is lower level).

When MainPage is loaded, it will navigate to index.html, which contains a button. When user presses the button, it will call function showMessage() (defined in Bridge class). Till now, everything works well.

But I want to call function defined in MainPage like printMessage() from lower level Bridge.cs code, how?

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Bridge _bridge = new Bridge();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyWebView.NavigationStarting += MyWebView_NavigationStarting;
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void _bridge_EReportFromBridge(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri navigationUri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/html/index.html", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Debug.WriteLine("......................navigate the url");
        MyWebView.Navigate(navigationUri);
    }

    private void MyWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(".................MyWebView_NavigationStarting() is executing");
        MyWebView.AddWebAllowedObject("nativeObject", _bridge);
    }

    public void printMessage(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("message: {0}", message);
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>

        function func1() {
            // 首先判断我们对象是否正确插入
            if (window.nativeObject) {
                //调用的我们消息函数
                window.nativeObject.showMessage("message, from index.html");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-top:100px">
        <button id="fun1Btn" onclick="func1();">Call method 2</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bridge.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace BridgeObject
{
    [AllowForWeb]
    public sealed class Bridge
    {
        public void showMessage(string message)
        {
            new MessageDialog("Frome Bridge.cs: NativeMethod() is invoked!", message).ShowAsync();

            // Call MainPage function printMessage(), how?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call function defined in MainPage from Windows Runtime Component,there is no direct way to achieve.But you can first notify index.html and then notify the mainpage to call the function by html.

Bridge.cs:

Pass the message to index.html via an asynchronous method.

```
[AllowForWeb]
    public sealed class Bridge​
    {​
        public IAsyncOperation<string> showMessage(string message)​
        {​
           new MessageDialog("Frome Bridge.cs: NativeMethod() is invoked!", message).ShowAsync();​
            return Task.Run(() =>      {​
                return message;​
            }).AsAsyncOperation();​
        }​
    }
```

index.html:

Receive the message and notify MainPage.

```
function func1() { 
            if (window.nativeObject) {​
                var result = window.nativeObject.showMessage("message, from index.html");​
                result.then(function (myMessage) {​
                    window.external.notify(myMessage);​ // send to MainPage
                });​
            }​
        }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

First subscribe **ScriptNotify** event in order to receive the information from html.When triggered,you can call the function you want.

```
public MainPage()
        {​
            this.InitializeComponent();​
            MyWebView.NavigationStarting += MyWebView_NavigationStarting;​
            MyWebView.ScriptNotify += MyWebView_ScriptNotify;​
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;​
        }

private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {​
            printMessage(e.Value);​
        }
```